# increase size of an image proportionally across browsers / devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the image I'm working with:

[image]

and this is the site:

http://btwnthelin.es/

I already have the image on there, just as-is with no sizing specification applied to it, but it's far too small.

I would like to increase to size proportionally, depending on the device or browser, to fit sizably in the top of the window, like a proper headline.

How can I achieve this while making sure that it renders in a good way across browsers and devices? i.e. I don't want to just brute force set the size of it to look good on the browser I'm currently using.

I'm using the template fullpage.js

Comment: What you're looking for is [responsive design](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=responsive+design+working+with+images). Your question is pretty broad for SO, but you can find a wealth of information on the web.

Comment: Are you looking something like image set in width of different browser as well in mobile browser ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the width to 100%

```
.fp-tableCell img {
height: auto;
width: 100%;}
```

Comment: whoa. rad. thank you. check it out! http://btwnthelin.es/